# Paymill: How do I simulate a failed payment while testing?

Tags: ruby, payment-gateway, payment, stripe-payments, paymill

**Background**

- Developing an app using [Paymill's subscription billing](https://www.paymill.com/en-gb/documentation-3/reference/api-reference/index.html#document-subscriptions) feature.
- Making use of the [Ruby wrapper](https://github.com/dkd/paymill-ruby), I have created a `PaymentProvider` class and spec as below.

**Question**

How do I make a test payment fail? (e.g. card is declined, or card expired in future subscription payments)

[Stripe would let me do this using special card numbers](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#how-do-i-test-specific-error-codes) but there doesn't appear to be any such documentation *(in English)* for Paymill.

---

**payment_provider.rb**

```
class PaymentProvider
  Paymill.api_key = ENV['PAYMILL_PRIVATE_KEY']

  def self.start_new_subscription(email, description, token)
    offer = Paymill::Offer.find(ENV['PAYMILL_OFFER_ID'])
    client = Paymill::Client.create(email: email, description: description)
    payment = Paymill::Payment.create(token: token, client: client.id)
    subscription = Paymill::Subscription.create(client: client.id, offer: offer.id, payment: payment.id)
    subscription.id
  end
end
```

---

**payment_provider_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PaymentProvider do

  describe "#start_new_subscription" do
    it "returns a subscription id, starting 'sub_' when successful" do
      email = "mike@mike.com"
      description = "me"
      token = get_payment_token
      subscription_id = PaymentProvider.start_new_subscription(email, description, token)
      expect(subscription_id[0,4]).to eq('sub_')
    end
  end

  def get_payment_token
    # Simulate the JavaScript bridge we would use in production
    params = {
      'transaction.mode'        => 'CONNECTOR_TEST',
      'channel.id'              => ENV['PAYMILL_PUBLIC_KEY'],
      'jsonPFunction'           => 'any_string',
      'account.number'          => '5500000000000004',
      'account.expiry.month'    => 3.years.from_now.month,
      'account.expiry.year'     => 3.years.from_now.year,
      'account.verification'    => '111'
      #'presentation.amount3D'   => BigDecimal('10.00'),
      #'presentation.currency3D' => 'GBP'
    }
    http = Net::HTTP.new('test-token.paymill.de', 443)
    http.use_ssl = true
    response = http.get url_query_string(params)
    response.body.scan(/tok_\w*\b/).first # Use a regex to pull the token from the (not-quite-JSON) response
  end

  def url_query_string(hash)
    "/?" << URI.escape(hash.collect{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join('&'))
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of today, there are no special credit card numbers to simulate those problems. However, due to demands from the community, this is currently in the backlog for being implemented. I'd suggest to send an email to the support, to show interest on this feature. The more requests, the faster the feature will be implemented.

EDIT: PAYMILL now offers a special MasterCard number, which will fail if a certain combination of expiration month and year is used. For instance, the card 5105105105105100 will fail due to RESPONSE_BACKEND_BLACKLISTED if the expiration date is sent as 02/2020.

Comment: The complete list of combinations for expiration dates and error codes can be found here: https://developers.paymill.com/guides/reference/testing#how-do-i-test-credit-card-specific-error-codes-

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use a string rather than a number for the verification value.

```
'account.verification'    => 'abc'
```

This will as of my knowledge result in a failed payment even when using the `CONNECTOR_TEST` mode.